# How to put a transparent image over a div containing a pdf in iframe

Tags: css, html

I have a Div consists of an iframe to display a pdf. I just want to safe my pdf by putting up a transparent image over the iframe. So that nobody can download the pdf.
I am using following code :

```
<div id="tobecovered">
    <p>your content...</p>
    <img src="./img/transparent.png" class="cover" />
</div>

div#tobecovered{
    position: relative;
}
div#tobecovered img.cover{
    position: absolute;
    /* position in top left of #tobecovered */
    top: 0; /* top of #tobecovered */
    left: 0; /* left of #tobecovered */
}
```

Its working fine in Chrome but not working in Mozilla Firefox. Can anybody help ?

Comment: Just so you know, this will not stop people from downloading your PDF, by any means. If someone wants it, they'll get it and with this method in particular, it would be EXTREMELY easy to get it.

Comment: I was thinking ... did you try to create completely transparent image in photoshop. And just put it for a cover. That way you don't need to add transparency or opacity and it might cover the iframe, because it does only if there is lower opacity than 1. (that I've heard). and may be you have to put some z-index ... try it :)\

Comment: @Seer : Its working fine. No one can download it by any method now. We have tried every method to download the pdf. But it was working perfectly in chrome but not in any other browser. That was my question..

Comment: @SatishSaini Give me a link, I'll give it a shot at downloading it :)

Answer (score 0):

That is what I think of:

The new HTML:

```
<div id="tobecovered">
    <p>your content...</p>
    <div class="cover"></div> <!--for example-->
</div>
```

And the new CSS:

```
div#tobecovered{
    position: relative;
}
div#tobecovered div.cover{
    background: url(images/./img/transparent.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 100px; /*for example*/
    height: 100px; /*for example*/
    position: absolute;
    /* position in top left of #tobecovered */
    top: 0; /* top of #tobecovered */
    left: 0; /* left of #tobecovered */

    opacity: 0.0; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

Or if you want change `background: transparent` with `opacity: 0.0; filter:alpha(opacity=0);`

Thats if you have image, and when you have iFrame it will be buggy. So try to create completely transparent image in photoshop. And just put it for a cover. That way you don't need to add transparency or opacity to the cover element and it might cover the iframe, because it does the bug only if there is lower opacity than 1. (that I've heard). and may be you have to put some z-index ... try it :)

Comment: Live that buddy... I have already corrected it. Just tell me how this code will work in firefox as well. ?

Comment: If you want try with opacity. Change `background: transparent` with `opacity: 0.0; filter:alpha(opacity=0);` or whatever value you want. It works even in IE6.

Comment: Could you please modify the code written by me according to your answer ?

Comment: I don't know did you mean that, but I've editted my answer the way it has to be and the way it wokrs for me. Or you mean to edit your post ?

Comment: Suppose my content in my question is :
<iframe id="fraDisabled" src="1.pdf" frameborder="0" width="800" height="600" ></iframe>

Here I want to protect this pdf with transparent image. But this code is not working is I am taking a pdf to protect but working for everything else like text data or any other image. What is the problem with pdf ?

Comment: that's a bug if I am not wrong. this happens with iFrame of YouTube also. the YouTube ones can be fixed but for that one it is difficult to say. Read that [link](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/883893-div-over-pdf-iframe) If you can understand what are they doing. Because I've tried but nothing happened.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help :)

Comment: I don't know if I helped because I didn't really told you a solution to the problem, but I hope I helped somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

Give `max-width; max-height` of 100% to image:

```
div#tobecovered img.cover{
    position: absolute;
    /* position in top left of #tobecovered */
    top: 0; /* top of #tobecovered */
    left: 0; /* left of #tobecovered */
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```